# Run a function on multiple ranges in a matrix at once (in Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I have the following matrix:

```
MatrixA =
     1    10    50
    23    45    76
    71    81    91
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
    78    89    91
     2     3     4
```

I would like to run the `var` function for multiple ranges in each column. More specifically, I would like to calculate `var` for rows 1 through 3, 2 through 4, 3 through 5, etc. for each column.  The output I would like would be:

```
1281.33  1260.33   430.33
1281.33  1564.33  2216.33
1566.33  2004.33  2496.33
    ...      ...      ...
```

I was thinking the syntax would be something along the lines of:

```
var(MatrixA([1 2 3]:[3 4 5],:))
```

but this (obviously) does not work.

I can do this using loops, but I was wondering if there is a solution to this that does not involve loops?

Comment: If the `var` function is a linear transformation on element-wise functions of `MatrixA`, you can efficiently implement this as a finite impulse response filter.  Otherwise, you probably need a loop.

Comment: Also note that loops in MATLAB aren't slow, what's slow is performing a large number of distinct (non-vectorized) operations.  So something in the style of `arrayfun` is not going to help performance, even if it avoids an explicit loop.  You seem to want to call `var` many times... a loop is as fast as any other way to do that.

Comment: a loop it is then.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of one loop using [`hankel`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) function to create the ranges:

```
V = [];
for C = MatrixA,
    V = [V, var(hankel(C(1:3),C(3:end))).'];
end
```

For instance if `C` contains the first column of `MatrixA` then

```
>> hankel(C(1:3),C(3:end))
ans =
     1    23    71     1     4
    23    71     1     4    78
    71     1     4    78     2
```

and

```
>> var(hankel(C(1:3),C(3:end)))
ans =
       1281.3       1281.3       1566.3       1902.3         1876
```

Answer (score 1):

You could be a little creative with `bsxfun` and `reshape` to compute an index array and then compute the variances:

```
n = 3;
idx = bsxfun(@plus, 1:size(MatrixA, 1) - n + 1, (0:n - 1)');
B = reshape(var(reshape(MatrixA(idx, :), 3, [])), [], size(MatrixA, 2));
```